# devise ignoring `after_sign_up_path_for`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have the following controller

```
class Vendor::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    redirect_to new_vendor_company_path
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    vendor_company_quotes_path(resource.secret)
  end
end
```

and this spec

```
describe "POST create" do
    it "should create a new vendor" do
      profile = attributes_for(:company)

      post :create, { company: profile }

      expect(response).to redirect_to vendor_company_quotes_path(assigns(:company).secret)
    end
  end
```

and my spec is failing, because I'm not beign redirect to `vendor_company_quotes_path`. Seems like devise is ignoring my overrided method.
Before anyone ask, my route is `devise_for :companies, path: "vendors", controllers: { registrations: "vendor/registrations" }` and I'm not using the `confirmable` module

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb?

Comment: Already posted on the end of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your override in the `ApplicationController`

Comment: same behavior, no success